# Cannot run simple JavaFX application on RPI3 with GLES enabled

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi3, gluon, javafx-11

I am trying to run a JavaFX application on RaspberryPI 3B+ with hardware acceleration enabled as it described in [gluon documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/embedded/) and [this live video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jmcvk4BX3yw). I was able to run the application with GTK and software renderer, but it turned out to perform no better than a javascript application launched in chrome kiosk.

I use official Raspbian built for 32 bit ARM(hf). Video drivers and full-kms enabled. Latest [Liberica JDK 11](https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-11.0.4%20for%20Embedded/) and [Gluon JFX11 for armv6hf](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).

Here is my attempt to run with hw acceleration (most is configured by default in JDK props):

```sh
java --module-path=/opt/jfx \
     --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics \
     -Dprism.verbose=true \
     -Dprism.debug=true \ 
     -Djavafx.verbose=true \
     -Djavafx.debug=true \
     -Djavafx.platform=monocle 
     -Dglass.platform=Monocle \
     -classpath *:app.jar io.frontless.desktop.Main
```

Which exits with following output:

```sh
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle
Loaded /usr/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so from java.library.path
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory
Loaded /usr/lib/libglass_monocle.so from java.library.path
Dispman: Cannot open display
* failed to add service - already in use?
```

Following parameter works, but with software rendered graphics (very low performance):

```sh
-Djavafx.platform=gtk
```

From [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jmcvk4BX3yw) published on Oracle channel it is obvious that it is possible to run JFX applications on Raspberry PI with HW acceleration. 
But all similar problems I could google ether do not provide correct solution or marked as "unsolvable".